# Phone Orientation Impacting View of Entries

Tags: swiftui, ios16

I have an app that allows the user to select categories to use in tracking expenses. There is a box that contains an icon and category name for each category **selected** by the user and another box containing an icon and category name for each category that is **available** to use. Tapping on a category in either box will removed the category from the tapped box and display the category in the other box.

**The Problem**
Placing the phone in the standard portrait mode displays all the categories in both boxes. When the phone is rotated to landscape mode, the currently **selected categories** don't appear on the display.

**How it Works**
To draw the display, the portrait view has the two boxes stacked on each other while in landscape mode the boxes are next to each other. Therefore there are different functions to draw the two screens but one function to display the currently selected categories and one to display the available categories. Shown below is the landscape function ShowLandCategories that draws the boxes and associated text. The GetCurrentCategories function is called in both portrait and landscape modes to display the currently selected (in use) categories.

**Observed**
I have observed that the currently selected categories will display in landscape mode if the **List** container is removed (needed to delete custom categories). Also if I place a breakpoint after the ForEach container in GetCurrentCategories(), I can see all the selected categories in the console. And finally, I tried removing the ZStack and Rectangle() from ShowLandCategories() to see if there was a problem with ZStack--it didn't have any impact on the view.

I'd be happy to show additional code if requested.

```
struct ShowLandCategories: View {

    @State private var presentAlert = false
    @State private var presentDetail: String = ""

    @EnvironmentObject var categories: CategoryModel

    var g: GeometryProxy

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            HStack {

                // start left half of landscape screen
                VStack {
                    Text("Current Categories")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)

                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(height: g.size.height * 0.65)
                            .border(Color("Dark Green"), width: 4)

                        ScrollView {
                            GetCurrentCategories(g: g, presentAlert: $presentAlert, presentDetail: $presentDetail)
                        }
                    }

                    ShwCurrentText()
                        .padding(.top, 3)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                    Spacer()
                }

                // start right half of landscape screen
                VStack {
                    Text("Available Categories")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)

                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(height: g.size.height * 0.65)
                            .border(Color("Dark Green"), width: 4)
                        
                        ScrollView {
                            GetAvailableCats(g: g)
                        }
                    }
                    ShwAvailableText()
                        .padding(.top, 3)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                    Spacer()

                   ... additional code here for alert and toolbar
                }
            }
         }
      } 
   }
```

This structure is called in both portrait and landscape views, but only displays the current selected categories in portrait view. The ForEach is filtering the categories that are currently in use.

```
struct GetCurrentCategories: View {

    var g: GeometryProxy
    @Binding var presentAlert: Bool
    @Binding var presentDetail: String

    @EnvironmentObject var categories: CategoryModel

    var columns: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.fixed(55)),
        GridItem(.fixed(145))
    ]

    var body: some View {

        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            List {
                ForEach($categories.catItem.filter{ $0.catInUse.wrappedValue }) { $item in
                    Button {

                        // must have a zero balance to remove
                        if item.catTotal == 0.0 && item.catNum != 0 {

                            // custom category?
                            if item.catCustom == false {   // no

                                withAnimation {
                                    // Change the state of category
                                    item.catInUse = false
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            presentAlert = true
                            presentDetail = item.catName
                        }
                    } label: {
                        LazyVGrid(
                            columns: columns,
                            alignment: .leading,
                            spacing: 6
                        ) {
                            Image(systemName: item.catPix)
                                .resizable()
                                .foregroundStyle(Color(colors[item.catNum % colors.count]))
                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)

                            Text(item.catName)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                                .background(item.catTotal != 0.0 ? Color(.systemRed) : Color("Dark Green"))
                                .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                        }
                        .frame(height: 33)
                        .padding(.leading, g.size.width * 0.04)

                        // don't allow deletion of categories with nonzero balance
                    }.deleteDisabled(item.catTotal != 0.0)

                }.onDelete(perform: deleteCurCat)  
            } 
        }
       ... not showing deleteCurCat() 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling most of the day on this, I got the landscape **selected** categories to display correctly by removing the ZStack, Rectangle(), and ScrollView ("start left half of landscape screen"). It appeared that replacing ScrollView with Group fixed the display of entries. I not sure why scrollview would impact the view this way. Below is a updated listing of the function.

```
struct ShowLandCategories: View {

    @State private var presentAlert = false
    @State private var presentDetail: String = ""

    @EnvironmentObject var categories: CategoryModel

    var g: GeometryProxy

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            HStack {

                // start left half of landscape screen
                VStack {
                    Text("Current Categories")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)

                    GetCurrentCats(g: g, presentAlert: $presentAlert, presentDetail: $presentDetail)
                        .frame(height: g.size.height * 0.65)
                        .border(Color("Dark Green"), width: 4)

                    ShwCurrentText()
                        .padding(.top, 3)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                    Spacer()
                }

                // start right half of landscape screen
                VStack {
                    Text("Available Categories")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)

                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(height: g.size.height * 0.65)
                            .border(Color("Dark Green"), width: 4)
                        
                        ScrollView {
                            GetAvailableCats(g: g)

                        }
                    }

                    ShwAvailableText()
                        .padding(.top, 3)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
```